# bat cmd or vb script to move specific files from one location to another location

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

can someone help me with a bat cmd to move specific files from one location to another location

my file structure

**Source location**

```
E:\Test1\2011\18\5730547\5730552\html
E:\Test1\2011\18\5730547\6430552\html
E:\Test1\2011\38\7730140\2330582\html
E:\Test1\2011\19\5718547\5730552\html
```

wherein `html` folder contains `css` folder, `xml` and `html` files.

I want to move only file name contains `testcase.html` and `images.html` files from the above location to below location

**Required location**

```
E:\Final1\2011\18\5730547\5730552\html
E:\Final1\2011\18\5730547\6430552\html
E:\Final1\2011\38\7730140\2330582\html
E:\Final1\2011\19\5718547\5730552\html
```

Please help me

Comment: Are there files named testcase and images in each of the css, xml and html folders? If so you are going to end up overwriting it everytime you copy the next one if they have the same filename...

Comment: in my "required location", there will not be any testcase.html and images.html files.

Comment: I didn't mean in the destination folder, I meant the source folders.

Comment: yes in my source folder testcase.html and images.html will contains (name will be same in all folders i.e. testcase and images)

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (testcase.html images.html) do (
xcopy E:\Test1\2011\18\5730547\5730552\html\%%a /s E:\Final1\2011\18\5730547\5730552\html\*1.*
xcopy E:\Test1\2011\18\5730547\6430552\html\%%a /s E:\Final1\2011\18\5730547\6430552\html\*2.*
xcopy E:\Test1\2011\38\7730140\2330582\html\%%a /s E:\Final1\2011\38\7730140\2330582\html\*3.*
xcopy E:\Test1\2011\19\5718547\5730552\html\%%a /s E:\Final1\2011\19\5718547\5730552\html\*4.*
)
```

They will be copied with numbers 1-4 appended to the filename otherwise they will be overwritten each time the next folders copy is copied to the same destination folder.

Comment: Great. If this answered your question you should check the tick next to it to show it as accepted.